# Relative angular velocity between two bodies

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

I was studying circular motion and came across a formula for the relative angular velocity between two bodies. I didn't find any kind of demonstration. Is it simply a determined concept, just like the vector product or the angular velocity vector?[image]

Comment: The instantaneous relative angular velocity of two objects is just the angular velocity of one of them in the instantaneous inertial reference frame of the other. Think about a Galilean transformation into the frame of $A$ or $B$, and compute the angular velocity there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this equation:

$$\vec{v}=\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}$$

or

$$\vec{v}\times \vec{r}=\left(\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}\right)\times \vec{r}\tag 1$$
[image]

if you write all vectors in components of the S' coordinate system you get:

**2D case**

$$\vec{r}=r_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{x'}$$
$$\vec{v}=v_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{x'}+v_y\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{y'}$$
$$\vec{\omega}=\omega_z\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{z'}$$

in (1)

$$(v_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{x'}+v_y\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{y'})\times r_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{x'}=\left(\omega_z\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{z'}\times r_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{x'}\right)\times r_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{x'}\tag 2$$

thus:

$$-v_y\,r_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{z'}=-\omega_z\,r^2_x\,\hat{\vec{e}}_{z'}$$

or:

$$\omega_z=\frac{v_y}{r_x}\quad, \omega_{AB}= \frac{(V_{AB})_y}{r_{AB}}$$

this is your equation

Comment: why w pointing in the direction of z?

Comment: In 2D Space you have three degrees of freedom two translations x and y and one rotation about the z axis